# Convenient way to manage text once I turned it into a link in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Once I right click a text in draw.io and select "link..." the text element becomes very hard to manage: I can only select it by dragging a rectangular select box around it, and even then I can't edit the text or change the link's location.

what's the sane way to manage the text element once it linkified?

Answer (score 1):

(here for users who did not find another way)

The only way I found so far is to select the text element using the method mentioned above, then choosing 'edit>edit link' , deleting the link content completely and pressing 'Apply'.
This effectively un-linkifies the text and makes it manageable again. after I'm done changing it, I linkify it back again.

Short versions for those who only want to move or edit the text: when selected the text element's pivot can be dragged with the mouse even when it's a link. also, you can choose 'edit>edit data' (or Ctr+M) to edit the text of a link.

Still, a right-click context menu is needed.